# Getting latest modified file and passing as input to a subprocess

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, motion

I have code which prints the latest file path of an image snapshot that is saved when motion is activated, I'm trying to use this file path as input to the next part of my code which converts the image to leave only the blue blobs. Any help is appreciated, I'm new to code.

```
#!/bin/bash/python

import os
from subprocess import  check_call

path = '/..'
os.chdir(path)
files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getmtime)

newest = files[-1]
if newest == "Thumbs.db":
        'newest = files[-1]

newest = [path+"/"+newest]
a = newest

print newest
```

##### convert to blue blobs

```
check_call(["sudo","convert","imgIn.jpg", "-posterize","2","imgOut.jpg"])

check_call([ "sudo",'convert', 'imgIn.jpg', '-matte', '(', '+clone', '-fuzz',     57%', '-opaque', 'black', '-transparent', 'blue', ')', '-compose', 'DstOut', '-    composite', 'imgOut.jpg'])
```

How do I use the file path of newest as imgIn.jpg?

Comment: What have you done to collect and save the file path?

Comment: I'm using Motion and a usb webcam to take a snapshot (.jpg) each time motion is detected (a dart on a dartboard)

Comment: noooo. Not the picture, the filepath of the picture... :)

Comment: Ha sorry, I'm not sure I use the code in the first part.. real beginner here :) It prints the file path to the terminal, with [ ] though

Comment: Where does it save the file?

Comment: A folder on my desktop, '/home/pi/Desktop/...'  and the converted file in a different folder.

Comment: The top part of the code prints the last saved image, which would be the last motion activated snapshot, to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a function called `get_latest_file()`:

```
from os.path import isabs, getmtime
from os import getcwd, listdir, path


def get_latest_file(p):
    if not isabs(p):
        p = path.join(getcwd(), p)
    files = sorted([path.join(p, x) for x in listdir(p)], key=getmtime)
    return (files and files[-1]) or None
```

This will get you the latest file sorted by modified time and returning the last/newest matching file for a given directory.

**Note:** One thing to note here in the above function is that you need to build up a list of absolute paths for the sorting key `getmtime()` to work correctly or it will throw `OSError`(s) since `os.listdir()` gives you a list of "names" in a given directory as relative names.

**Example:**

```
get_latest_file("images")
```

Then you can pass the result of this to your `check_output()` call:

```
latest_image = get_latest_file("images")
check_call(["sudo", "convert", latest_image, "-posterize", "2", "imgOut.jpg"])
```

**Update:** You *could* then finish this off by writing one more function called `convert_image()` like this:

```
from os.path impomrt splitext
from subprocess import check_call


def convert_image(inf):
    base, ext = splitext(inf)
    outf = "{0:s}-converted{1:s}".format(base, ext)
    check_call(["sudo", "convert", inf, "-posterize", "2", outf])
```

**Update #2:** In terms of passing in the path for `get_latest_file()` you have probably three choices here:

```
IMAGE_PATH = "/path/to/images"                   # hard coded

image_path = raw_input("Enter path to image: ")  # prompt user

image_path = sys.argv[1]                         # from the command line
```

**Side Note:** Your [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is not quite right; it should read: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

References:

- [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)
- [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)
- [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)
- [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)
- [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm on the right track. Still having problems though, do I need to insert the path of the folder into that code?

Comment: Into the ``get_latest_file()`` function call? Yes. You *could* get the path from teh command-line via ``sys.argv[1]`` for example.

Comment: Thanks, you're very helpful, I'm still quite confused about how to put this together in one working script.

Comment: Give it a try and post it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you get stuck or want someone to look over your attempt.

Comment: @JamesMills Stack Overflow is the site that helps debug code, Code Review only improves working code.

Comment: @Hosch250 Wrong; There is a "Vote to Close" because "Question asking help with debugging". i.e: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) is **NOT** a debugging or trouble shooting service (*although admittedly a lot of us oblige!*)

Comment: I keep getting this error? OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/images'

Comment: @OwenLyons We would need ot see the full traceback to understand the error more precisely; ``OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...'`` means precisely what it means! Check the path you're using and the function you're calling.

Comment: [1] Started stream webcam server in port 8081
[1] File of type 1 saved to: /home/pi/Desktop/DartProj/DartORG/20150514054817.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/DartProj/fun.py", line 14, in <module>
    get_latest_file("images")
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/DartProj/fun.py", line 11, in get_latest_file
    files = sorted([path.join(p, x) for x in listdir(p)], key=getmtime)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/images'

Comment: ``line 14, in <module> get_latest_file("images")`` <-- Did you really copy/paste the examples I wrote as-is without modification?

Comment: Haha yep complete beginner, I replaced "images" with the folder path as I had asked earlier about, same result :)

Comment: Sorry @OwenLyons this is getting into the "discussion" etiquette of SO. *Please avoid extended discussions in comments* I recommend you ask a different more specific question :)

Comment: @JamesMills I'm sorry, but as a regular at CR, questions containing broken code or asking for help implementing a new feature are closed immediately.

Comment: @Hosch250 Questions seeking to debug problematic code (*especially quite complex debugging problems*) are closed immediately here too :)

Comment: OK, I just didn't want the OP to needlessly cross post.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Hosch250 No neither did i! I was hoping the OP had enough to write a mostly correct implemtnation! This discussion is getting out of hand :)